# gzcompress and gzuncompress in php

Tags: php

I use `gzcompress()` on the value passed in php for example:

```
$value=gzcompress("hello");

myphp.php?q=$value;
```

Then I `gzuncompress()` it in `myphp.php`:

```
$q=$_GET["q"];
gzuncompress($q);
```

but I get this warning:

```
gzuncompress(): data error
```

Why is this not working?

Answer (score 1):

You need to urlencode() the compressed data. You cannot simply slap what will be essentially random-looking binary garbage into a url like that. The odds are high that at least **ONE** of the characters in the compressed data will be a URL metacharacterrs, e.g. `+`, which gets mangled to a `' '` (space) character when decoded. So,

```
$value = urlencode(gzcompress('hello'));
```

PHP will do the url decoding for you automatically when it populates $_GET, so the decoding end will be simply

```
$q = gzuncompress($_GET['q'])
```

as before.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. It works. But this link on the email http://mydomain/myphp.php?q=x%9CK%04%00%00b%00b doesn't work, when being clicked, nothing happened. Mind you have a look please?